# Applying attributes to fo:block based on certain conditions

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm trying to construct a `xsl:function`, `xsl:template` or anything that will bring me the correct solution for the following.

I've got a XSL:FO with a lot of `<fo:block>` elements which need to contain all kinds of attributes to style the text in that element (eg. `font-size`, `letter-spacing` etc...). I want to reduce the redundancy of adding all those attributes inline in the elements. I already improved this by adding all those attributes to the elements and making their value be set from a variable (eg. `<fo:block font-size="{$titlefontsize" />`).

Though, I'd like to take it one step further, ideally, I'd like something like this, which obviously does not work:

```
<fo:block my:applyFontStyle('h2') margin-left="10mm">...</fo:block>
```

Please note, that I still need to be able to apply attributes which apply to the same element.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#attribute-sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using named attribute sets (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#attribute-sets).

You can do things like:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="heading">
  <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:attribute-set name="h2" use-attribute-sets="heading">
  <xsl:attribute name="font-size" select="'1.5em'" />
<xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="heading2">
  <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="h2" margin-left="10mm">
...
```

The `xsl:attribute` in an `xsl:attribute-set` are evaluated each time, so you can do things like:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="id">
  <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id()" />
</xsl:attribute-set>
```